# Compare Columns using VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert corresponding `Column C` values in `Column D` when Column A and Column B value matches.

For example:

Column A2 is equal to Column B2, now Column C2 value is posted on Column D2

OR

Column A7 is equal to Column B3 then Column C3 value is posted on Column D3

For detail please see the screen shot so you have idea what i am trying to do.

[Please click to see the screenshot][1]

The code which i am trying is below but it is not working properly, it is just giving only one cell value:

```
Private Sub ForComparing_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range
Dim lastRowA As Long, lastRowB As Long, lastRowC As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    lastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of column A
    lastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of column B
    lastRowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of column C
    For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & lastRowA)   'loop through column A
        'check if cell in column A exists in column B
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B2:B" & lastRowB), cel) = 0 Then
            .Range("D" & cel.Row) = "No Match"
        Else
            .Range("D" & cel.Row) = .Range("C" & cel.Row)
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

**Edited 1:**

Please see the output of this code below:
[Click here to see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXE4c.jpg)

`Column A3` should compare with `Column B5` because the value `D` is equal in this case, and then it should print `Column C5` value to `Column D3`

Furthermore, it should give value in `Column D` for every value of `Column A` but it stop after first 4 values.

Thanks for your time.

**Edited 2:**

[Please see the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGhu6.png)

What you have just edited is perfectly right, but i want to do this for each `Column A` value.

I want to compare each `Column A` value with `Column B` and then corresponding `Column C` value is copied on `Column D`.

Comment: Show us the code you have already tried and explain where the problem is. Keep in mind you can record a macro to get you started.

Comment: Read about `Match` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim lastRowA As Long, lastRowB As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        lastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of column A
        lastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of column B
        For Each cel In .Range("A1:A" & lastRowA)   'loop through column A
            'check if cell in column A exists in column B
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B1:B" & lastRowB), cel) = 0 Then
                .Range("C" & cel.Row) = "No Match"
            Else
                .Range("C" & cel.Row) = cel & " has match in column B"
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

***EDIT :***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range, rngC As Range, rngB As Range
    Dim lastRowA As Long, lastRowB As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of column A
        lastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of column B
        For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & lastRowB)   'loop through column B
            'check if cell in column A exists in column B
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A2:A" & lastRowB), cel) = 0 Then
                .Range("D" & cel.Row) = "No Match"
            Else
                .Range("D" & cel.Row) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(.Range("C2:C" & lastRowB), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cel, .Range("B2:B" & lastRowB), 0), 1)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

See image for reference.

[image]

However I'm still very doubtful of what you are trying to achieve. You are matching only first 4 values from column A as mentioned by you in question "*but it stop after first 4 values*". Still, as per my solution it will match 4 rows from `Column A` to `Column B` and if it matches then corresponding `Column C` values will be displayed in `Column D`. If there's no match then `Column D` will display `No Match`.

Comment: Hello Mrig,

I have edited the question as you advised, can you please guide me that what error i am committing in the above code.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @AmmadAhmed - instead of `.Range("C" & cel.Row) = cel & " has match in column B"` try `.Range("D" & cel.Row) = .Range("D" & cel.Row)`

Comment: @AmmadAhmed - I'm not in front of my system so it's not tested.

Comment: No problem, i have tried this but this is not working, and did you mean: 
`.Range("D" & cel.Row) = .Range("C" & cel.Row)`  
instead of    
`.Range("D" & cel.Row) = .Range("D" & cel.Row)`   
because i have to copy data from column C to column D when A and B columns are matched

Comment: @AmmadAhmed - Oops, it should be `C` as mentioned by you.

Comment: No problem, i have tried but unfortunately it is not working properly

Comment: Thanks again, i have tried this, please look in my edit question.

Comment: @AmmadAhmed - Oh, now I understood your question completely, will give you solution tomorrow.

Comment: No problem, thank you very much for your generosity and kindness.

Comment: @AmmadAhmed - Is this your final update of there's anything else to add to it. It will be better if your can precisely ask what you really want because what you are asking seems quiet simple but you are making it very complicated.

Comment: @AmmadAhmed - Instead of `For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & lastRowB) ` use `For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & lastRowA)`

Comment: @AmmadAhmed - Try this and let me know as I'm travelling and can't test it right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you are too good, that's what i needed, and many thanks for your guidance, i will make sure that next time i post my query properly.

Comment: @AmmadAhmed - If it solved your issue kindly accept it as answer by clicking tick mark at top left of answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub compare()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do While Cells(i, "A").Value <> ""
    If Cells(i, "A").Value <> Cells(i, "B").Value Then
        Cells(i, "C").Value = "No Match"
    Else
        Cells(i, "C").Value = "Match"
    End If


    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Declare a counter (`i`) and then set a loop to iterate through Column A. The loop will keep going until a cell is found in column A that is blank.

Within the loop, for each row, you compare the 2 respective cells and change the value of the cell in Column C . Finally you add 1 to `i` on each iteration of the loop so it goes through each row.

An easier approach is without VBA using the below formula:

`=IF(A1=B1,"Match", "No Match")`

Comment: `i` has to be `Long` not `Integer`. Excel has more rows than integer can handle. Also there is no advantage using `Integer` anyway so you should [**always** use `Long`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) unless you need to communicate with old APIs.